# .NET Core WCF: How to Upgrade 'dotnet-svcutil' Version

Tags: wcf, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, svcutil.exe

Visual Studio 2017
.NET Core 2.2
Reference to WCF .NET Framework (4.6.1)

when update service reference,
These lines appear at the top of the reference.cs file:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.1")]
```

How do I upgrade the version of the dotnet-svcutil ?

Answer (score 0):

WCF dotnet-svcutil tool is provided by vs2017(Core1.0 SDK), and it use the 1.0 version to generate the client proxy class by default.
VS2019 already has the latest version of dotnet-svcutil tools built in (call the service by adding the service reference), along with Core SDK(2.0+)
[image]
We could also use Nuget Package manager to install it, and then generate the client proxy class manually.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil --version 2.0.0
dotnet-svcutil http://contoso.com/SayHello.svc -d D:\
```

**Result.**
[image]
Please refer to the below link.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-svcutil/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Are you sure it's dotnet-svcutil and not the dotnet-svcutil.xmlserializer

Comment: If you install the Dotnet-Svcutil tool with Nuget, and then generate the client class manually, does the decoration attribute change to the Dotnet-Svcutil tool version you installed? on my side, it works as expected. Or a little simpler, you can download vs2019 directly.

Comment: I installed version 2 but in the reference file everything remains in version 1

Comment: Vs2017 use dotnet-svcutil tool 1.0 version by default. Are you manually generating the client proxy classes by command? if so, you could try to verify the actual version by typing the below command in the Developer Command Prompt for VS . dotnet-svcutil --version.  I suggest you download vs2019 which has  2.0 version built in.

Comment: If we don't install vs2019, we need to install the tool with the above command first, then view the version in the Developer Command Prompt window for VS and manually generate the client proxy class, because vs2017 uses the 1.0 version of the tool by default.